# wso2 identity server facebook login with Oauth2.0

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to use wso2 identity server Facebook login with Oauth2.0 not saml ?

i searched several docs for this but i couldn't find a proper answer for this any ideas of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IS federate authentication with Facebook using "Oauth2.0". You can refer [WSO2 offcial document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Logging+into+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials) for more details.